# Matplotlib Animation: Plot a changing number which corresponds to increment

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created an earthquake animation that plots earthquake epicenter locations over time.  I wish to add a number counter in the bottom left or right corner that changes with each epicenter plot.  So, each time an earthquake plots in the figure, the number increases.  How would I edit my script (attached below), that would allow for this annotation to the plot?  Thanks.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python


############################################################################################
#                                                                                          #
#  This script uses Matplotlib, the Basemap function, Matplotlib's animation function,     #
#  and numpy to iteratively plot a list of earthquake epicenters with the map centered     #
#  around Antarctica.                                                                      #
#  Created By:                                                                #
#  Date: 09/12/2015                                                                        #
############################################################################################

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
import csv

# Create the Figure Object
fig = plt.figure()


# Build the basemap:  In this case, using  mercator projection
antmap = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=26.729567, llcrnrlon=-127.041952, urcrnrlon=-63.409141, urcrnrlat=48.036699,  resolution='l')
# Draw the coastlines and color them black.
antmap.drawcoastlines(color='black', linewidth=0.3)

# Option 1: Fill the continents with gray color, oceans as blue color
antmap.fillcontinents(color='gray', lake_color='aqua')
antmap.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')

# Option 2: Fill map background with blue marble earth image
#antmap.bluemarble()

# Option 3: Fill map background Etopo topography (Figure will take longer to load)
#antmap.etopo()


# Open the earthquake data file using built-in open() function
eq_data = open('usquakes.csv')

# Create empty lists for latitudes, longitudes, and magnitudes
lats, lons = [], []
magnitudes = []
depth = []

# Assign variables x and y to longitude/latitude to be able to plot on map.
x,y = antmap(lons,lats)

def get_marker_color(magnitudes):
    if magnitudes < 3.0:
        return ('go')
    elif magnitudes < 7.0:
        return('yo')
    else:
        return ('ro')
# Read each line in comma-separated, 3-column file (Could also use CSV-module).
i=0
for i, line in enumerate(eq_data.readlines()):
    lats.append(float(line.split(',')[0])) # 0 is first column, split on comma.
    lons.append(float(line.split(',')[1]))
    depth.append(line.split(',')[2])
    magnitudes.append(float(line.split(',')[3]))
    mag = np.array(magnitudes)*2
    i = i + 1


#mag = np.array(magnitudes)*2  # Scale the magnitudes
# For scaling the magnitudes in a list, this has to be performed using np.array.

# Close earthquake data file
eq_data.close()
#antmap.plot(x,y,'ko',markersize=8)[0]

#### Begin Animation Function ######
def animate(i):
    x,y = antmap(lons[i], lats[i])
    marker_string = get_marker_color(magnitudes)
    antmap.plot(x,y,marker_string, markersize=mag[i])

# Call FuncAnimation, using an interval of 100 ms, and on Mac OSX, set blit=False
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  interval=10, blit=False)

# Show the figure!
plt.show()

# Optionally save animation as .mp4 file (must have ffmpeg installed).
#animation.save('earthquake_animation.mp4', writer="ffmpeg")
```

Comment: Haven't read through your code, but I'm pretty confident you should be able to do something good enough with matplotlib.pyplot.annotate

Comment: Hey Julien, I'll check that out.  Thanks!

Comment: why do you increment `i` during the `enumerate`? surely `enumerate` increments `i` automatically (not that you're using is, but still...)?